Hartshorne Lemma III.2.8, exactness of direct limits of sheaves
In Lemma III.2.8 of Hartshorne, the author asserts that the direct limit of sheaves preserves exactness.
I can't seem to find this earlier in the book, so I'm wondering if there is a general result that this follows from, of which I am supposed to be aware?
Or does one need to check that this holds in this particular case?

I think this is something you just need to check. One way to do this is to show that direct limits (indeed arbitrary colimits) of abelian sheaves commutes with taking stalks.

The direct limit is an exact functor. You can look at the sequence given on the stalks and prove that it's exact using this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121122/why-do-direct-limits-preserve-exactness
